# Low CouchDB performance for randomized operations

Tags: performance, mongodb, couchdb, benchmarking, ycsb

I am benchmarking the performance of Couchdb and Mongodb using the YCSB benchmarking tool. Unfortunately it seems I am doing something wrong because the difference in performance for single, random operations is huge:

**Workload A** (50/50 read/update), 16 query threads, 120 sec runtime (results are very similar with 20 minute runtimes):

CouchDB 1.6.1: Overall throughput: **1076 ops/sec**, 99th percentile read latency of 13ms,  99th percentile update latency of 13ms

MongoDB 3.0.6: Overall throughput: **11203 ops/sec**, 99th percentile read latency of 1ms, 99th percentile update latency of 1ms

As you can see, CouchDB is terribly slow for randomized reads and updates. The documentation recommends using bulk operations which might be fine for inserts, but I do not see how I would realize bulk reads considering YCSB is asking for reads one by one.

**Testing environment:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on a virtual box on an i7 host with VT-D enabled, 2 cores, 2gb ram (although i get similar results with a dedicated machine)
- Working set/db easily fits in ram
- Localhost server, no hardware-network-latency (results are similar on a hardware cluster)
- Everything that is supposed to improve performance mentioned in the CouchDB documentation, especially HTTPD options and C-extensions for simplejson are set correctly
- The couchdb driver has been written by me using the Ektorp persistence API recommended on CouchDB's website. The code is straightforward and the drivers I have written for other database systems work fine.

**What I have tried to improve throughput:**

- Using bulk inserts for the load phase. This makes CouchDB a lot faster, but still a factor of 7 slower than MongoDB, this is consistent with the benchmark published [here](https://www.arangodb.com/2014/12/bulk-inserts-mongodb-couchdb-arangodb-dec-2014/), using the same CouchDB version.

**Possible explanations for CouchDB's slowness:**

- Updates have to be done by requesting the document, modifying it and resubmitting it to the database, which is causing high latencies. However this does not explain the low read-throughput

Question: **Do you see any other ways of improving CouchDB's performance?**

**Edit**: Delayed_commit is set to true in couchdb, so I am starting to doubt the forced-fsync as the cause.

Comment: There are many things that might be unconsidered by your benchmark: Did you use persistent HTTP connections to CouchDB? Do you do caching by E-Tag? Are views involved or _all_docs? What is the used write concern used for updating mondogb documents? If you plan on using CouchDB like a huge read-write bucket for your documents, it might not fit. Have a look at the couchdb file layout and the "compaction" process.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is simple: CouchDB ensures that all writes are hits disk with fsync() call while MongoDB allows to keep them in memory for a while and tell you that everything is fine. Until next accidental shutdown when you loose your data. RAM-vs-disk is the main performance factor between them.

Next goes protocol: HTTP is text, while MongoDB uses own binary one. No need to tell, that binary protocols are more compact and efficient.

But the main problem here is that your benchmark is synthetic. You assumes that your database is used for silly read-writes, like a data bags, while databases are being used for more complex operations like queries, index lookups, joins, data validation and so on. And here business logic matters.

For more real benchmark, you should take some application and make it work with both databases and benchmark business workflow with them, not blind read/write. Pretty sure, your numbers will be equalized because business logic is much more slower than any database.

So I'm sorry that you waste your time on this.

Comment: The in-memory feature is a option in mongodb, that can be be set for each write operation. @marcel-sufryd did not specifiy this. The rest of your arguments seem true.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the default behavior regarding persistence for CouchDB, which I was not aware of. I understand your criticism about a synthetic benchmark, but in this particular case the synthetic benchmark actually represents the most common operations for the given use case.